# How to parse Minecraft ops.json to display all oped users, their UUID's and the total amount of oped users

Tags: php, json, parsing, variables, minecraft

Sorry if the title of this doesn't make sense, I'm very new to working with JSON files in PHP. I looked almost everywhere and reworded my question multiple times, every answer I get doesn't seem to work my JSON file, not sure if Minecraft does something different or if I'm missing something. Thank you to anyone who responds to this!

**Goal**

> List all operators on my Minecraft Server on my website in a proper format with their UUID's and OP Level. I would also like to show the current amount of people OPed on the server.

[Example Photo of what I imagine it looking like (of course with better CSS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmIh8.png)

Here's my PHP Code

```
$serverdir = "../Minecraft Server/";
$json_url = $serverdir."ops.json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

<?php
foreach ($data as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}
```

This code currently just spits out Array 5 times I have to change **$data** to **$data[*1-5*]** to get an actual output but it outputs the username, UUID, and level but I don't see how to format this type of output.

Here's the JSON File

```
[
  {
    "uuid": "3afa9281-a239-453f-9538-49b57d9f2d06",
    "name": "Deathx90",
    "level": 2,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "461e6427-1d5c-43e3-b4ee-f8361884c3a2",
    "name": "Command_String",
    "level": 2,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "1ab6c2d3-6cae-4937-81af-cf348ca0f16c",
    "name": "sarcazsm",
    "level": 2,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "83619f6c-d259-4da2-868b-eba807e15b37",
    "name": "Monke_Syndrome",
    "level": 2,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  },
  {
    "uuid": "584f7a2f-2f8c-453e-a459-6ce8a683f04c",
    "name": "Kreyo813",
    "level": 2,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": false
  }
]
```

After Solving:

[Here is the final product, I add some additional looks to it as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mY1E.png)

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($data);`, you'll see the structure `json_decode()` returns. What you'll get is a multidimensional array (an array with arrays) so in your foreach loop, `$value` will be an array with the data. To get specific values, you need to echo: `$value['uuid']`, `$value['name']` and so on.

Comment: I tried something like that and it didn't seem to work. I easily could've been doing something wrong. The object notation worked for me but I may try this in the future. Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with php object notation

```
$Object = json_decode($json);
foreach($Object as $obj){
    echo $obj->uuid,'<br>',
         $obj->name,'<br>',
         $obj->level,'<br>';
}
```

You can use count to get number of users, example only

```
$Object = json_decode($json);
$count = count($Object);

echo '<div><p>Number of OPed Users: (',$count,')</p></div>';
foreach($Object as $obj){
   echo '<div><p>',$obj->uuid,'<br>',
         $obj->name,'<br>',
         $obj->level,'</p></div><hr>';
}
```

Comment: Let me try this real quick, it looks like something I saw before but it didn't seem to work.